# Mechanics - Elastic energy stored in a cylinder placed on a tabletop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

> A cylinder of length $l$, mass $m$, area of cross section $A$ and Young's modulus $Y$ is placed on a table. Calculate the elastic energy stored in the cylinder.

**My workout:**

The infinitesimal compression in $x$ part of the cylinder due to the remaining $l-x$ part on top of it would be 
$$d\Delta l = \frac{mg(l-x)dx}{l\cdot YA}$$
On integrating LHS from $0$ to $\Delta l$ and RHS from $0$ to $l$, I get
$$\Delta l = \frac{mgl}{2AY}$$
Elastic potential energy is given by 
$$E = \frac 1 2 \frac{YA}l \Delta l$$
Substituting values, I obtain
$$E = \frac{m^2g^2l}{8YA}$$

However **the answer mentioned in my textbook is** $$\frac{m^2g^2l}{6YA}$$
If any errors are apparent in my working, please point them out. Otherwise, please confirm that the textbook's answer is indeed wrong.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook is not incorrect. The issue here stems more from a misuse of an equation because the condition to use said equation isn't met. The equation $E = \frac{1}{2}\frac{YA}{l}\Delta l^2$ is only valid when the displacement is linear/ when the strain is constant.

The actual definition of axial strain $\epsilon$ is $\epsilon = \frac{du}{dx}$, where $u$ is the displacement within the body.

The $\Delta l$ you use is the total change in length of the bar/ the displacement at the free end.

Note that when $\epsilon$ is constant, you can integrate the strain equation from $0$ to $x$ to acquire the displacement as a function of $x$ as below.

$$u(x) - u(0) = \epsilon x$$

For a fixed end at $x = 0$ and $u(l) = \Delta l$ at the free end, it is immediately clear that $\Delta l = \epsilon l$ or $\epsilon = \frac{\Delta l}{l}$ as you usually see.

However, in this case, the displacement is a quadratic function as you have found yourself. Going by the actual strain definition, your first equation is $du = \frac{mg(l-x)}{YAl}dx$.

Integrating both sides from $0$ to $x$ with dummy variable $\xi$ used for the right side:

$$\int_{0}^{x} du = u(x) - u(0)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{mg(l-\xi)}{YAl}d\xi = -\frac{mg(l-x)^2}{2YAl} + \frac{mgl^2}{2YAl}$$

The strain as a function of $x$ is $\frac{mg(l-x)}{YAl}$ by taking the derivative of $u$ or dividing the stress by $Y$. So notice that this strain is not constant throughout the body.

Now you need the more accurate total strain energy definition. The total strain energy is the volume integral of half the product of the stress $\sigma$ times the strain as below.

$$E = \frac{1}{2} \int_{V} \sigma \epsilon dV = \frac{1}{2} \int_{V} Y\epsilon^2 dV$$

In the case of an object with a cross-sectional area $A$, length $l$, and constant strain, this equation reduces as below.

$$E = \frac{1}{2} \int_{V} Y\epsilon^2 dV = \frac{1}{2} YA\frac{\Delta l^2}{l^2} \int_{0}^{l} dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{YA}{l}\Delta l^2$$

I bet that looks familiar. Now let's find the strain energy for your variable strain.

$$\begin{align}
E &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{V} Y\epsilon^2 dV = \frac{1}{2} YA\int_{0}^{l} \epsilon^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} YA\int_{0}^{l} \frac{m^2g^2(l-x)^2}{Y^2A^2l^2} dx\\ &= \frac{m^2g^2}{2YAl^2} \int_{0}^{l} (l-x)^2 dx
= \frac{m^2g^2l}{6YA}\\
\end{align}$$

So the text isn't incorrect. You actually have an underestimation because you've assumed the strain within the cylinder is constant. In reality, the strain is increasing toward the fixed end of the cylinder at $x = 0$.

Comment: Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.

Comment: This isn't really so much a "do my homework for me" type of question as much as it is a chance to rectify misuse of common equations and definitions while facilitating an understanding of the more general case of a concept. They did their homework, and their work is correct up until the misused equation which led to their confusion.

Comment: @JeqHar [Check my work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6097/127931) questions are also off topic, and fall under the "homework and exercise" umbrella.  This site attempts to focus on conceptual questions, and showing your work and asking "where did I go wrong?" isn't really a conceptual question.

Comment: Even if it wasn't meant as a conceptual question, I've provided the answer to a conceptual flaw in reasoning that led to their confusion.

Comment: Still one shouldn't answer homework and exercise tagged question you could have left the last part of integration for the user. One should help the questioner to find where he is wrong.

Comment: @Dr_Paradox I'll grant that I could have left the last integration for them, but if they can integrate as they've already shown in their problem statement, then I doubt I've taken much from them with that integral. And they already had the answer from their text. As far as helping them know where they are wrong, from the context of the problem, the questioner was thinking in terms of a specific case of strain and elastic energy. They needed to be brought up to a slightly more general approach that can be applied to problems extending well beyond this one.

Comment: @JeqHar And in doing so, you've reinforced the undesired behaviour.  Just showing work and asking "where did I go wrong?" aren't good conceptual questions for the site.  The issue is, if people wind up getting answers even though it's off topic, they are more likely to ask another off topic question.  Users browsing the site may also see that it got an answer, and feel that it is okay to ask similar questions.  This is something that is often discussed by the community; and the consensus seems to be that we don't want that.

Comment: @JMac I see it as a hidden conceptual question in this problem that needed an answer from how the question was posed. It felt less like a "where did I go wrong?" question and more like an "I am applying this concept as correctly as I learned it, but I am focused on a specific case exactly because of how I learned it" situation. In my eyes, they didn't go wrong. They just didn't know better. But I'm only saying this from experience in how poorly I've seen these concepts introduced without condition. Overall, even if off-topic in how it was intended, I feel that this question needed an answer.

Comment: @JeqHar That's the thing though, practically every homework question that someone solves wrong will have a "hidden concept" which is causing the trouble; either that or a math error.  I'm sure it doesn't _feel_ like a "where did I go wrong" question, because you know the concepts behind it; but as asked, that is all that it is.  Even though the issue the OP is facing is conceptual, they aren't asking a conceptual question; and off-topicness depends on the question, not on what the answers are.

Comment: @JMac Me knowing the concepts behind it is exactly why I'm almost certain it isn't a "where did I go wrong" question in the respect you mean. Where exactly did this person go wrong? They have the correct process and use the "correct" equation (from the answer they produced). The issue is the condition of their problem is different from what the equation given was derived for. There's a difference in misplacing a tool and not having it, and I saw this as a good opportunity in the likely chance that they don't have something to provide it for the benefit of the questioner, off-topic or not.